# How to correctly combine CGAffineTransform matrices?

Tags: ios, swift, matrix, cgaffinetransform

An image should be scaled and transformed.

Depending on how the transform matrix is composed, I get different results:

```
// A) This produces the desired result, scales the image and translates the image independently from each other
let transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: translation.x, y: translation.y).scaledBy(x: scale.width, y: scale.height)

// B) This also produces the desired result
let scaleTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale.width, y: scale.height)
let translateTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: translation.x, y: translation.y)
let transform = scaleTransform.concatenating(translateTransform)

// C) This does not produce the desired result, it also scales the translation, so a 10x scale results in a 10x translation
let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale.width, y: scale.height).translatedBy(x: translation.x, y: translation.y)

// Transform image
image = image.transformed(by: transform)
```

If `.concatenating` means multiplying and `.scaledBy` or `.translatedBy` means adding the two matrices, why does A and C not produce the same results given that matrix order should not matter when adding them together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a coincidence that the multiplication and the addition of a scaling matrix and a translation matrix have the same result.

In the general case, `scaledBy` and `translatedBy` don't mean adding, they are shorthand for concatenating two transforms, which is a matrix multiplication. Matrix multiplication is only commutative for diagonal matrices (matrices that only have non-zero values in the diagonal line), so `S * T` generally isn't the same as `T * S`.

Look up `$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGAffineTransform.h` for what each function does:

- `CGAffineTransformTranslate`: t' = [ 1 0 0 1 tx ty ] * t
- `CGAffineTransformScale`: t' = [ sx 0 0 sy 0 0 ] * t
- `CGAffineTransformRotate`: t' =  [ cos(angle) sin(angle) -sin(angle) cos(angle) 0 0 ] * t
- `CGAffineTransformConcat`: t' = t1 * t2

This means that when you use `CGAffineTransformConcat`, `t1` must be the transformation that you're applying and `t2` must be the matrix that you're transforming. In other words, `scale.translatedBy` is equivalent to `concat(translation, scale)`, not `concat(scale, translation)`. When using `concatenate` as a method, this makes the operation look backwards because of its mathematical definition.

Comment: If `scaledBy` and `translatedBy` are also multiplications, then why isn't B and C producing the same results? Both would be `scale matrix` x `translation matrix`.

Comment: @Manuel, `a.concatenating(b)` is `b x a`.

Comment: The method description for `func concatenating(_ t2: CGAffineTransform) -> CGAffineTransform` says:  `t’ = t1*t2`. Doesn't that mean `a.concatenating(b)` is `a x b`?

Comment: @Manuel, you're right, the ones with swapped arguments are the other transforms. See latest edit.

Comment: If you mean that I am right that `scaleTransform.concatenating(translateTransform)` is `scale x translate`, then why isn't B and C producing the same results?

Comment: @Manuel, I don’t mean that. X.concat(Y) is X x Y, but X.scale(Y) is Y x X, and X.translate(Y) is also Y x X. Examples A and B are the same, C is the one that is different.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @zneak said, the order of matrix operations matters as matrix multiplication (concatenation) is not commutative. That is A * B ≠ B * A in general.

Since the order is reversed in C, it produces a different result.